# How to Create Column with Binary Variable that Indicates if Another Column has Certain Factors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to create an binary variable column that shows simply indicates whether or not an existing column is equal to "R" or "P". If it is equal, i would like the new column to read "1", and if there is a blank observation I would like it to read "0".

I would like this:

```
Person    Play       Key  
A           1         R
B           2         P
C           3         
D           4         R
E           5
```

To become this:

```
Person    Play       Key      Indicator
A           1         R           1
B           2         P           1 
C           3                     0
D           4         R           1
E           5                     0
```

I have tried:

```
df$Indicator <- (df$Key == 'R' | 'P')
```

But that doesn't work. I get the error `Error in df$Indicator <- (df$Key == 'R' | 'P')" :  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

Besides I'm not sure that would provide the binary indicator I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any of these approaches. You were almost close as you were using a code like `df$Indicator <- (df$Key == 'R' | 'P')` but the proper form would be `df$Indicator <- df$Key == 'R' | df$Key =='P'`. That will produce `TRUE/FALSE` values, so you can use `as.numeric()` to make them `0/1`. Here the code:

```
#Code 1
df$Indicator <- as.numeric(df$Key %in% c('R','P'))
#Code 2
df$Indicator <- as.numeric(df$Key == 'R' | df$Key== 'P')
```

Output:

```
  Person Play Key Indicator
1      A    1   R         1
2      B    2   P         1
3      C    3             0
4      D    4   R         1
5      E    5             0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Person = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Play = 1:5, 
    Key = c("R", "P", "", "R", "")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Another option would be (All credits to **@ChuckP**):

```
#Code3
df$indicator <- ifelse(df$Key == 'R' | df$Key== 'P', 1, 0)
```

Which will produce same output.

Comment: As long as you're giving coices @Duck don't forget good old `df$indicator <- ifelse(df$Key == 'R' | df$Key== 'P', 1, 0)`
`

Comment: @ChuckP You are right, I will add that code to the answer! Great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
expl <- data.frame(Person = LETTERS[1:5], Play = 1:5, Key = c("R", "R"," ", "P", " "))
expl$Indicator <- expl$Key == 'R' | expl$Key =='P'
print(expl)
expl$Indicator2 <- as.numeric(expl$Key == 'R' | expl$Key =='P')
print(expl)
```